# What's the song playing in episode 59 of Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood?

Tags: music-identification, fullmetal-alchemist

I can't find it with Google, Shazam, or anything like that. It's episode 59: Lost Light at 14:41.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there any way you could link to a clip of that part of the episode?  People without access to the episode might be able to help, but can't without the audio.

Comment: It just sounds like Gregorian chanting. I don't think it's a specific song

Comment: Not sure it's name, but producer composer Akira senju did the soundtrack out for the series which you can view... https://m.soundcloud.com/tags/fullmetal%20alchemist%20brotherhood

Comment: Song when Roy Mustang loses his sight? I think it is just background noise. But seems to be connected to the one in this episode, starting at 3 minute mark in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HK7WtwvQPyI And that one is called Amnestris Military March: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6QqZfvE3Fw

Comment: Certainly not Gregorian chant. Also doesn't appear to be either of the songs listed in the episode information.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is one of the variations of the [**Dissident's Creed** by **Akira Senju** (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCOlcr954DY) (with some instruments).

Soundtrack length seems to be the same (about 1:55).

[Sample from the FMA (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/v6h6h4i120g?t=950)

[Plus comment from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FullmetalAlchemist/comments/4jnix9/theme_of_comedic_relief/):

> I'm not sure, there are variations of songs that play all the time in
> FMAB that don't seem to have official releases (ie, Dissident's Creed
> in Episode 59)

[image]